# React JS props updated, but not rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The essence of this program is that when you enter any value into an input, you get 2 random numbers and 2 random strings. Since the onChange event is worthwhile during the input of the number, it must be changed and rendered. But the numbers do not appear. However, using React Developer Tools, I see that the values are generated.

All code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        class TextInput extends React.Component {
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {dropDownList: null};
                this.eachRender = this.eachRender.bind(this);
            }


            eachRender() {

                this.eachNumbers = [Math.random(0,10), Math.random(0,10)]; //Numbers are generated randomly
                this.eachString = ["One random string", "Another random string"]; //Strings are also generated randomly, in order to simplify the code, they were given static values

                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;

                if (text !== ""){
                    this.setState({dropDownList: <DropDownList numbers = {this.eachNumbers} someString = {this.eachString}/>});
                }
                else this.setState({dropDownList: null});
            }
            render() {
                    return ( <div>
                        <input type="text" id="text" onChange={this.eachRender}>
                        </input>
                        {this.state.dropDownList}
                    </div> )
            }
        }

        class DropDownList extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.eachTask = this.eachTask.bind(this);
        this.state = { items: [ //The data should be presented as follows
            {id: 1, item: this.props.numbers[0], href: this.props.someString[0]}, 
            {id: 2, item: this.props.numbers[1], href: this.props.someString[1]},
        ] };
    }
    eachTask(items) {
            return(
                <li key = {items.id}>
                    Rund Number: <b>{items.item.toFixed(3)}</b> <br></br>
                    Rund String  <b>{items.href}</b>
                </li>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.state.items.map(this.eachTask)}
            </ul>
        )
    }


    } 

     ReactDOM.render(
     <TextInput />, document.getElementById("app")
     )

</script>

    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

I think the problem revolves around this line of code:

```
this.state = { items: [ 
        {id: 1, item: this.props.numbers[0], href: this.props.someString[0]}, 
        {id: 2, item: this.props.numbers[1], href: this.props.someString[1]},
    ] };
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: There are many things I can see wrong with your code, but answering them may be out of scope for Stackoverflow, I can recommend posting it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and also reading through the official documentation, specifically the part on 'Thinking in react'

Answer (score 1):

Use `setState` if you want to change the value of `this.state`.

[Per React docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

> Never mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried to do, but React produces an error of the form: 

`Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component is repeatedly calls setState inside a componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor english;

In `DropDownList`: render `props` directly instead of `state`;
It does seems to create a brand new `DropDownList` in method `eachRender`, but the only difference is `props`, you can print it in console.
welcome suggestion:)